# How to make a common auto increment id for two tables

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables, each has an id field without auto-increment and set to BIGINT.

I need to make a general increment so that when I add data to one table and then to another, their id increases by 1 unit and never matches in both tables

Comment: And how do you propose to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mathematically impossible

Comment: Strawberry, In postgresql it is possible, is it really mysql so weak

Comment: It's not possible, because it's not possible

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Try explaining and you may get alternate approaches to your problem..

Comment: Imagine one table starts at 1 and the other table starts at 10. What happens after you insert 10 rows in each table? See? We cannot satisfy the stated criteria.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, what if you make one table with a AUTO_INCREMENT and simulate those other tables with views where in view one you filter the even id's and view two you filter the odd id's..  That should be pretty close to your requirement..

Comment: Actually if you start one table at 1 and the other at 9223372036854775807 then theoretically it would work, because you would run out of numbers before they overlapped.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing anyway? I mean, if the ids should never match in both tables, why would you want to tie them together with the same auto incremented value? Use a positive value as auto increment on one table, and a negative value on the other, problem solved.

Comment: Instead of two tables you can use one table.

Comment: Info: Auto Increment in `MySQL`  works for positive number even-though `0` will not be inserted, it will be changed to next AI number.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, I'm not a MySql guy, I work mostly with SQL Server, so I didn't know MySql don't support negative auto-increment values. Still the question remains - why bound both tables to the same auto-increment value?

Comment: *"I'm not a MySql guy, I work mostly with SQL Server, so I didn't know MySql don't support negative auto-increment values. "* @ZoharPeled fair enough, you can better remove that comment about using a negative `auto_increment` to not confuse people  *"Still the question remains - why bound both tables to the same auto-increment value?"* agree it is a wierd request..  i would make this with basic table with `auto_increment` and two views where you filter on even id's in one view and in the other view  on odd id's ...

Comment: @Avrȃhȃ́m This seems more and more like an [xyproblem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Please [edit] your question to explain why you think you need such a construct to begin with, and if you could include a demonstration on how you envision the rows in both tables should look like, I'm sure it would help you get a good answer to your question.

Comment: To add to @ZoharPeled 's last comment, See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common pattern but unfortunately MySQL doesn't support table-independent sequences. MariaDB, MS SQL Server and Oracle all have the Standard SQL SEQUENCE feature but MySQL does not.

What you can do is create a third table just for the purpose of generating the sequence. Insert to your sequence table first, then use the generated key value to insert to your other tables.